# Как склеить выдаваемые циклом списки в один

Tags: python

Всем привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть цикл на питоне, который выдает такой результат:

```
[1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1]
```

(строк может быть и больше, т.е. каждый раз неизвестно сколько их)

Как мне склеить выдачу, чтобы из каждого столбца списка выбиралось минимальное значение, т.е. получилось бы:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: из каждой **строки** ?

Comment: из каждого списка)

Comment: Вы хотели сказать из каждого **столбца**? Смотря на русские слова желаемый результат вводит в заблуждение

Comment: да, сравниваем столбцы в списках

Comment: а код, который выводит это на экран вы из принципа не показываете? ;)

Comment: Не хотел грузить лишней инфой, тк код совсем не идеален, а пока цель была просто решить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да пусть будет так...

```py
>>> list(map(min, zip(*[
    [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
    [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1],
])))
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, это помогло решить)